# SpringMVC url path pattern replacement

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I have a url path pattern in SpringMVC which looks like:

```
/person/{personId}/address/{addressId}
```

and I have personId = 2 and addressId = 3
Is there an easy way for me to generate

```
/person/2/address/3
```

using a utility method within SpringMvc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look at [UriTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplate.html) class.
you can construct your own UriTemplate from your URL, and then expand the template variables.

```
UriTemplate template = new UriTemplate("http://example.com/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}");
Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<String, String>();
uriVariables.put("booking", "42");
uriVariables.put("hotel", "1");
System.out.println(template.expand(uriVariables));
```